# What settings required to retry message to from GCP pub/sub in java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud-gcp

I am new to GCP pub/sub and trying to resend a message which is not acknowledged (ack/nack). In subscription at GCP console dashboard, I have mentioned:
[image]

In my java code, I have created a subscriber

```
public Subscriber createSubscriber(String subscriptionId, MessageReceiver receiver) throws MessagingException {
        Subscriber subscriber = null;
        ProjectSubscriptionName subscriptionName = null;
        String projectId = getProjectId();
        if (Objects.isNull(projectId) || Objects.isNull(subscriptionId)) {
            throw new MessagingException(MessagingErrorCodes.MIX90810
                    + " Project Id/Subscription Id is null for subscriptionId = " + subscriptionId + " projectId= "
                    + projectId, MessagingErrorCodes.MIX90810);
        }
        try {
            subscriptionName = ProjectSubscriptionName.of(projectId, subscriptionId);
            subscriber = Subscriber.newBuilder(subscriptionName, receiver).setExecutorProvider(getExecutorProvider()).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new MessagingException(MessagingErrorCodes.MAX34540
                            + " Error occurred while creating the subscriber for the subscriptionId = " + subscriptionId
                            + "projectId " + projectId + "subscriptionName= " + subscriptionName,
                    MessagingErrorCodes.MAX34540, e);
        }
    enter code here
        return subscriber;
    }
```

I am getting messages on my receiveMessage(PubsubMessage message, AckReplyConsumer consumer) the first time but not getting again if I am not acknowledging the message. But if sending nack it's sending the message again.

```
@Service
public class MyMessageReceiver implements MessageReceiver {

    @Override
    public void receiveMessage(PubsubMessage message, AckReplyConsumer consumer) {
        System.out.println(message.getMessageId());
    }
}
```

should I need to mention other configuration to enable retry in case of not acknowledging the message as well?

Comment: Your ack deadline is 10s.

Comment: End after the timeout, did you receive again the message?

Comment: I received the message at the interval of 1 Hour. As in Subscriber.java is having `DEFAULT_MAX_ACK_EXTENSION_PERIOD= Duration.ofMinutes(60);`
To make custom retry time. I have to set duration in setMaxAckExtensionPeriod(Duration maxAckExtensionPeriod) function.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Anyway I can see the extended time is working fine in logs or dashboard

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the retry policy, the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#using_subscription_properties) says that Pub/Sub tries to redeliver the message, only if the acknowledgement deadline expires or if the subscriber nacks the message. Once the acknowledgement deadline passes, the message becomes a candidate to be redelivered. The redelivery may not be immediate as redelivery is performed on a best effort basis.

As already mentioned in the comments, the `DEFAULT_MAX_ACK_EXTENSION_PERIOD` is set to 60 minutes in [Subscriber.java](https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub/blob/master/google-cloud-pubsub/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/Subscriber.java#L405), which is the cause of this delay. The Ack deadline will continue to be extended (by the client library as a native functionality) until this duration is reached. Meaning, the unacked message is leased by the subscriber for 60 minutes and is not eligible to be redelivered within this period. The `setMaxAckExtensionPeriod(Duration maxAckExtensionPeriod)` is used to set a custom value to the maximum period a message’s acknowledgement deadline will be extended to.

Please also note that none of these values is a guarantee that the message will not be redelivered within that time frame. It is possible for the message to be redelivered before [maxAckExtensionPeriod](https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub/blob/master/google-cloud-pubsub/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/Subscriber.java#L421) due to network or server blips.

Comment: After setting setMaxAckExtensionPeriod(Duration.ofSeconds(20)). I am getting messages early but not in an interval of 20 seconds. Sometimes 1 min or even later.

Comment: Hi @RishabhJain, I updated the answer as per your comment.